# Image.width on IE browsers

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript (resizes images in blogspot blogs):

```
  var imageTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for(i = 0 ; i < imageTags.length; i++){
    if( imageTags[i].src.indexOf('/s400/', 0)>-1 ) {
      if(imageTags[i].style.width=='400px' || imageTags[i].width==400) {
      imageTags[i].style.width='556px';
        imageTags[i].style.height='368px';
      } else {
        imageTags[i].style.width='368px';
        imageTags[i].style.height='556px';
      }
      imageTags[i].src=imageTags[i].src.replace('/s400/', '/s556/');

    }
  }
```

it works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE (tested IE9) it seems to always get into the second branch, as if `imageTags[i].width==400` always evaluated to false. How can I fix in on IE browsers?

EDIT:
As suggested I temporarily added an alert to display the width of the image and on IE9 it was.... 416. It looks like IE added margins to the width from the html.

Comment: Please, please, please... create a variable for imageTags[i]. It just adds clutter to the code, making it just slightly harder to understand/parse/read/maintain.

Comment: In the else block, could you output the width that's getting returned from `imageTags[i].style.width` somewhere?  Curious what IE 9 is calculating it at...

Comment: Yeah - I've heard that IE puts extra margin space on elements at times.  Not sure where the official documentation of this is, but I have seen posts where folks have similar issues in IE browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try `imageTags[i].offsetWidth==400` instead of `imageTags[i].width==400`
I suggest it because .width propertie only gets the `width` defined in the tag, whereas `.offsetWidth` gets the real width

Comment: Sorry, the correct is offsetWidth instead of innerWidth. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

Please run this and tell what you get - currently you resize and then load a new image

```
var imageTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0,n=imageTags.length,img,src,w,h,newImg; i<n; i++) {
  img =  imageTags[i];
  src = img.src;
  if(src.indexOf('/s400/', 0)==-1 ) continue;
  alert(img.width);
  if(img.width==400) {
    w=556;
    h=368;
  } else {
    w=368;
    h=556;
  }
  newImg = document.createElement("img");
  newImg.onload=function() { this.width=w; this.height=h}
  newImg.src=src.replace('/s400/', '/s556/')
  img.parentNode.replaceChild(newImg,img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I checked what was the width reported by IE and it was 416 instead of 400 (possibly margins were added?). So I just added an obvious hack to check for both 400 and 416.